# функция проверки позиции скролла

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть функция с помощью которой можно проверить "проскроллен ли скролл сайта до видимости определенного объекта":

```
function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
  var docViewTop = $(scroll).scrollTop();
  var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(scroll).height();

  var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
  var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

  return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}
```

допутсим `isScrolledIntView('footer')` вернет `true` если мы проскроллили вниз и "видим" футер.

Я бы хотел узнать, как можно изменить функцию и задавать ей параметры, чтобы определять допустим *проскроллен ли скролл `.testdiv`'a до `.li:last-child`, который находится в нём, т.е. проверять позицию скролла блока, а не всего окна по отношению внутренним объектам?

Answer (score 2):

Поскольку `offset()` рассчитывает положение элемента с учетом его сдвига (скрола), вам нужно сравнить лишь `offset()` одного элемента с другим:

```js
function isScrolledIntoView(elem, scroll) {
  if (scroll === undefined) scroll = window;

  var docViewTop = $(scroll).offset().top;
  var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(scroll).height();

  var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
  var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height()
  
  return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}

$('#container').scroll(function() {
  console.log(isScrolledIntoView('#elem', '#container'))
})
```

```css
#container {
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  margin-Top: 50px;
}
#inner {
  position: relative;
}
#elem {
  position: absolute;
  top: 300px;
  background: #ccc
}
#elem2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 400px;
  background: #ccc
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="inner">
    <div id="elem">test</div>
    <div id="elem2">&nbsp;</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Хотел бы заметить, что текущее условие `((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));` выполняется только если элемент виден целиком.

Comment: а как можно сделать чтобы на половину увиденное тоже возвращало true?

Comment: поменяйте местами `elemBottom`  и `elemTop`. Тогда получится что если хотябы немного видно элемент